# Capture the response of async axios call in react

Tags: html, reactjs, async-await, axios

```
 async  saveForm(data) {
     return await axios({
       method: "post",
       url: FORM_PORTAL_CONTROLLER_URL + 'savemoratorium',
       body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(res => 
        this.setState({ refNo: res.data.reference }))
  }
```

I cannot set set state which im getting from the request it gives me below error. The Post request executes perfectly. I want to capture the response and and change the state.function is inside a component. Following errors are in the console of the page and im getting a white page after this.

react_devtools_backend.js:6 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
react-dom.production.min.js:152 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: In the axios request replace `body` to `data`

Answer (score 0):

Add a validation before render

```
// Sample 1

      if(Array.isArray(refNo) && refNo.length){ 
        //your code
       }

//Sample 2

      {Array.isArray(refNo) && refNo.length? customRenderFunction(): null}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the root cause for this case. Its because I had a conflict with material ui node module. (makeEffect,useEffect)